# Обращение к картинке в css

Tags: css, веб-программирование, вёрстка, background

Сейчас верстал сайт, наткнулся на проблему, дал задний фон в css, но хочу его чуть уменьшить, как это сделать?

Вот пример:

```
.bg{
    background: url (img/first.png);
}
```

Так вот надо изменит чуть размер `first.png`, как к нему обратиться через css? Вариант с обрезкой картинки в пеинте или фотошопе откидывается сразу.

Answer (score 1):

Есть такое свойство [`background-size`](http://htmlbook.ru/css/background-size)
Оно масштабирует фоновое изображение согласно заданным размерам.